# Get ALL DIV (Or any element) in a Page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get all div's within a page using jQuery including nested divs?

```
$('div'); //returns outer but not inner

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, `$('div')` *does* return all divs. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: `//returns outer but not inner` That's not correct. What's your actual issue?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/MxSFG/ -- note that it alerts "2" for `$('div').length` because it includes both divs.

Comment: do you actually run your javascript before the divs?

Comment: Hmm...there must be another reason its not working for me.

Comment: @ryandlf: Why not post the actual code that's giving you issues? This is obviously not your actual code.

Comment: The code is somewhat complex...it might be easier to try and figure it out on my own. The fact that $('div') returns all div's within a page answers my question.

Comment: @ryandlf: Just be aware that it will only return divs *currently* on the page. People can stumble when making an asynchronous AJAX request. Also be aware the some jQuery methods only operate on the first element found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the DOM is loaded yo.

```
$(function() {
    console.log($('div'));  
    // [<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>], [<div id="inner"></div>]

    $('div').each(function(i, ele) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + ele);  
        // 0: <div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
        // 1: <div id="inner"></div>
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Shorthand for ready
$(function(){
  $('div');

  // or use the DOM method:
  document.getElementsByTagName('div');
});
```